# How can I draw a line of the raycast hit in game view while the game is running?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraRaycast : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;

    public LineRenderer laserLineRenderer;
    public float laserWidth = 0.1f;
    public float laserMaxLength = 5f;

    void Start()
    {
        Vector3[] initLaserPositions = new Vector3[2] { Vector3.zero, Vector3.zero };
        laserLineRenderer.SetPositions(initLaserPositions);
        laserLineRenderer.startWidth = laserWidth;
        laserLineRenderer.endWidth = laserWidth;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = cam.ViewportPointToRay(cam.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition));
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
            if (hit.transform.tag == "Interactable")
            {
                //print("I'm looking at " + hit.transform.name);
                laserLineRenderer.enabled = true;

                laserLineRenderer.SetPosition(0, ray.direction);
                laserLineRenderer.SetPosition(1, hit.transform.position);
            }
            else
            {
                //print("I'm looking at nothing!");
                laserLineRenderer.enabled = false;
            }
    }
}
```

When it detect a "Interactable" object i want it to draw green line from the mouse cursor to the point where the raycast is hitting.

Now it's not drawing anything.

Comment: If you need draw a line only for debugging, you could use `Debug.DrawLine`(https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html)

Comment: You should use `ray.origin` at index 0 instead `ray.direction`.

Comment: @whoo24 ray.origin draw a line but to the original position i wasand i  want to draw a line from my current mouse cursor position to the hitting point("Interactable").

Comment: `ray.origin` is world position of mouse point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a Render Texture or Image.
2. Take hit points from raycast and change the pixels of Image/Render Texture using [Texture2D.SetPixel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html)
3. To make line visible you can change pixels around the hit point. It will be line width functionality (Commonly used brush size).
4. You can use [GL.Lines](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.LINES.html)
5. You can use already available unity assets like [Easy 2D Lines](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/80393), [Mobile Paint](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/19803)